# How to put a label above a point of a line?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling, graphics

My intention is to put a line to points `{0,0,0}`, `{0,0,1}`, and `{0,0,2}` and make a label "DUMA" above the second pont, `{0,0,1}`. What I tried is the following:

```
Graphics3D[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}}, VertexLabels -> {2 -> "DUMA"}]}]
```

However, `VertexLabels` does not work in this context. Could you please help me how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}}, Line[{1, 2, 3}], 
   MeshCellLabel -> {{0, 2} -> Style["DUMA", Red, 14]}];
Graphics3D[{Dashed, reg}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. Is there any way to keep "DUMA" parallel to the line when rotating the figure?